# 404 Not Found nginx - Submitting a form

Tags: php, nginx

I'm working in laravel project, my form is submitted with ajax, 
The goal is to create images with "intervation image" using the data user inputs.

Actually, if my code To create 30 images takes us about 20/40 seconds, but if i want create 100 images or more it stop and return error:

```
404 Not Found

nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)
```

I thought it was due to php time limits, so I increased the limits:

**Resource Limits**

```
max_execution_time = 120
max_input_time = 120
memory_limit = 128M
```

But it return the same error, i can attach some screenshot of console
[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

> ERROR LOG

```
2017/06/21 08:39:44 [error] 2438#2438: *765 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 84.220.145.34, server: dixart.it, request: "POST /tool/postFinal HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock", host: "www.dixart.it", referrer: "http://www.dixart.it/tool"

2017/06/21 08:39:44 [error] 2438#2438: *765 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/50x.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 84.220.145.34, server: dixart.it, request: "POST /tool/postFinal HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock", host: "www.dixart.it", referrer: "http://www.dixart.it/tool"
```

**ACCESS LOG**

```
84.220.145.34 - - [21/Jun/2017:08:38:30 +0000] "POST /tool/upload/image HTTP/1.1" 200 67 "http://www.dixart.it/tool" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"

84.220.145.34 - - [21/Jun/2017:08:39:44 +0000] "POST /tool/postFinal HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "http://www.dixart.it/tool" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: Did you check the `access.log` from [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/logging-and-monitoring/) to see why it responds with 404?

Comment: yep! let me update the question

Comment: Ok i think then we need to see the code, i assume `/tool/postFinal` is stuck somewhere, hence the connection times out